# Использование массива из ассемблерной вставки

Tags: c, массивы, ассемблер

Делаю ассемблерную ставку в си. Должно, например, заменить нужный элемент массива на другую букву.

Пересылаю массив в функцию через

```
char fas3=rule2(&text2[0]);
```

А в функции вот такое:

```
__asm {
add [a], 1
mov [a], 's'
}
```

Почему не работает? Как сделать, чтобы работало?

Answer (score 3):

Не работает, потому что [a] - это адрес первой ячейки массива, который хранится где-то ещё. И операции вы совершаете с указателем, а не с массивом.

Нужно правильно сделать так:

```
__asm
{
    push eax       ; Сохранить состояние регистра eax
    mov eax, [b]   ; Прочитать в него адрес первого элемента массива
    mov [eax], 's' ; Записать в память по оному адресу новое значение
    pop eax        ; Восстановить состояние регистра eax
}
```

Ах, да, если функция целиком только из этого и состоит, то сохранять и восстанавливать состояние регистра не надо - компилятор всё сделает сам. Я подозреваю, что он это сделает в любом случае, но мало ли.

Comment: Спасибо.
Почему cmp [eax], [ebx] не воспринимается? 
Очень уж хочется сравнить два элемента массива, а он не дает.
eax, ebx заданы аналогично вашему eax.
Отладчик считает, что недопустимый тип оператора.

Comment: http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/readings/i386/CMP.htm - посмотрите таблицу допустимых операндов команды, там сразу видно, что не так. Кратко поясняю: r-регистр, imm - непосредственно число, m - ячейка памяти. И не отладчик - компилятор.

Comment: А [eax] не является r/m-byte? 
Если является, то получается противоречие с http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/readings/i386/MOV.htm , тк mov temp_char, [ebx]  у меня тоже не работает. 
Как все же сравнить их?

Comment: А temp_char разве не тоже память?)
Но вы смотрите точнее, что и с чем можно сравнивать. Даже на листочек перепишите - так почти во всех командах подобного типа.

Comment: Я, наверное, злоупотреблю вашей добротой. Получилось нечто такое:
   xor eax, eax
   xor ebx, ebx
   push eax 
   mov eax, [a]
   mov ebx, [a]
   add eax, j
   add ebx, j
   add ebx, i
   add i,1
   mov edx, [eax]
   mov temp_char, ebx 
   cmp edx, [temp_char]
   je change
На change он не переходит, хотя есть одинаковые элементы и он их считывает вроде как. Почему не переходит?

Comment: С прошлым разобрался, если чего.

Comment: Во-первых, связка push-pop используется для сохранения состояния регистров. То есть push до их использования и pop после=) К тому же нафиг их обнулять до пользования, если потом вы туда пишете?) Зачем лишняя переменная? У вас регистры для этих целей есть. Почему не переходит - смотрите в отладчике. Что-то там не так .з. У меня, к слову, почти такое же работает (при правильном объявлении и убирании лишних команд).

Comment: Или нет.
mov edx, [eax] 
Я правильно понимаю, что здесь в edx кладется элемент, находящийся по адресу [eax]?

Comment: Да, всё так. Причём, для экономии регистров можно даже класть в eax: mov eax, [eax]

Comment: Но в отладчике это выглядит совсем не так: он кладет в edx много цифр. И два одинаковые элемента не проходят проверку на одинаковость.

Comment: Проверяйте, что в eax было до этого. Может быть, вы не так объявили, может что-то не так сделали. Проверяйте) Или прочитайте пару статей про работу с памятью...

Comment: To @Алексей Сонькин . Большое спасибо за ссылку на Instruction Set с таймингом команд. Как Вы считаете, приведенные данные по тактам соответствуют только 386-му или для современных процессоров они не изменились?  По поводу, что писать в __asm  - почему не посмотреть какой код делает компилятор с оптимизацией -O3. Обычно код на удивление хорош.

Comment: Ну, измениться, конечно, изменились =)
http://developer.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf - для новых интелов. Там есть раздел INSTRUCTION LATENCY AND THROUGHPUT.
http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/47414.pdf - аналогично для AMD =)

Comment: To @Алексей Сонькин . Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну или так

```
__asm
{
    push eax       ; Сохранить состояние регистра eax
    mov eax, b[0]  ; Прочитать в него адрес первого элемента массива
    mov [eax], 's' ; Записать в память по оному адресу новое значение
    pop eax        ; Восстановить состояние регистра eax
}
```

Comment: И в чем вы видите смысл замены `mov eax, [b]` из ответа выше на полностью эквивалентное `mov eax, b[0]`?